# Is this not the "Private Beta"?

Tags: support, badges

As such (and perhaps this is better suited for SE Meta), why have no Beta badges been awarded?  I know I, personally, have fulfilled the requirements and I'm sure several others have as well.

Comment: I just got my badge, and looking at your profile you did too :)

Comment: Indeed!  I guess we're public now.

Answer (score 9):

Because we need to move out of private beta to get awarded badges about participating in the private beta. I participated in the vi/vim private beta and got that badge the day it went into public beta.

Comment: Ah!  OK, that makes sense.

Comment: Related feature request: [Allow commitments to be fulfilled even if a private beta fails](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/13253/75391)

Answer (score 4):

Today we entered the Public Beta phase and those who qualified, received the 'Beta' badge:

[image]